# tortoise svn checkout issue

Tags: svn, centos, tortoisesvn, svn-ssh

I have installed and created SVN repo in Centos. And I am using tortoise as svn client from windows 7. I want to use svn with svn+ssh format. So I have created private key with puttygen and copied the public key. And I pasted this public key in the root's .ssh/authorized_keys on centos in format

command="/usr/bin/svnserve -t -r /var/www/html --tunnel-user=root",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAAD root@1.2.3.4

where my repository location = /var/www/html, svn user = root.

And also I have saved the session called "myrepo" on putty. Then I tried to checkout the code using tortoisesvn by giving the URL of repository as svn+ssh://myrepo/svnrepo. But I got an error message like:

[image]

when I changed the key authentication to password authentication, it is working fine. And also checked the key with ssh, It is also working fine. But when I am trying with svn+ssh, It is showing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by updating the subversion on the CentOs server.